# Jade includes and blocks

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, pug, template-engine

I have many template pages (`index.jade, catalog.jade, contacts.jade` and so on), where I include some extra pieces of code (like `header_piece.jade` and `footer_piece.jade`) by `include`.

What I'm trying to do - I want to include something to the code, which is included by `include`. Hope it can be done using jade.

Here is my code:

```
index.jade:
body
  .wrapper
    include inc/header_piece

    append header
      .someextradiv
        | text

inc/header_piece.jade:
  block header
    .header
      a(href = '/') Home
```

What I expect to get:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="header"><a href="/">Home</a>
    <div class="someextradiv">Text</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

What I really get:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="header"><a href="/">Home</a></div>
  <div class="header"><a href="/">Home</a></div>
</div>
```

What I'm doing wrong and how to get desired result?

Answer (score -1):

I was able to get your desired results by doing the following:

index.jade:

```
body
  .wrapper
  include inc/header_piece

  append inc/header
    .someextradiv
    | text
```

Comment: Doesn't work. This part of code look illogical - "append inc/header".